# dpkg and insserv error when installing any package

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, 64-bit, glibc, binutils

When I try to install any package the following error occurs:

```
insserv: There is a loop between service runlcactivator and dns-clean if started
insserv:  loop involving service dns-clean at depth 1
insserv: Starting runlcactivator depends on plymouth and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package cups-browsed (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-core:
 xserver-xorg-core depends on udev (>= 149); however:
  Package udev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-intel:
 xserver-xorg-video-intel depends on xorg-video-abi-20; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-20 is not installed.
  Package xserver-xorg-core which provides xorg-video-abi-20 is not configured yet.
 xserver-xorg-video-intel depends on xserver-xorg-core (>= 2:1.17.99.902); however:
  Package xserver-xorg-core is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-xorg-video-intel (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                          Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.1) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic


Errors were encountered while processing:
 udev
 grub-common
 grub2-common
 grub-pc-bin
 grub-pc
 lightdm
 cups-browsed
 xserver-xorg-core
 xserver-xorg-video-intel
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. I edited your question so it is a little easier to read. To find your problem it would help if you add what exactly you were doing before the error occurs, i.e. how you try to install which package.

Comment: i am installing pakages ..   sudo apt-get install binutils...this command i m using to instal

Comment: for installing pakages it gives this error...I am not able to install any pakage..